# When looping through a pivot table array is still grabbing filtered data

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a pivot table that I loop through and populate an area based on the information in the table.  My issue is that the array is still gathering data that is filtered out.  Is there a way around this?

Here is the code to give an idea of what I am doing.

```
Do While count < managerCount – 1 

MGR = CStr(ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).RowFields(1).PivotItems(MGRCount + 1).Value)
late = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).GetPivotData("Count of Action Item ID", "Mgr", MGR, "Status to Plan", "Late").Value

If late = "" Then

     late = 0

End If

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

 lateProjects(count, 0) = MGR

 lateProjects(count, 1) = late

MGRCount = MGRCount + 1

count = count + 1

Loop
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PivotItems` collection contains all items, even if they are not displayed. However, you can check for `.Visible`!

Here's the full code:

```
Dim piv As PivotTable
Dim pivItem As PivotItem

Set piv = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

Do While count < managerCount - 1
    Set pivItem = piv.RowFields(1).PivotItems(MGRCount + 1)

    If pivItem.Visible Then
        MGR = CStr(pivItem.Value)

        late = piv.GetPivotData("Count of Action Item ID", "Mgr", MGR, "Status to Plan", "Late").Value

        If late = "" Then
             late = 0
        End If

        On Error GoTo ErrHandler

        lateProjects(count, 0) = MGR
        lateProjects(count, 1) = late
        MGRCount = MGRCount + 1
    End If
    count = count + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Or rather it did however when stepping through the code again it looks like it is still gathering some of the filtered data (the visible property is still appearing as true)

Comment: do you filter with the pivot functionality - or do you simply hide the rows/columns?

Comment: Sorry for the late response it was supposed to be filtering however i ended up just including the values then assigning them a value of zero than ignoring anything with a value of zero moving forward which solves the problem just not very eloquently.